# Identify a step up/down movement of scrollbar in gtk

Tags: c, scroll, gtk, scrollbar, gtk2

1. I have created a gtk scrolled window.
2. I had attached a gtk tree view to it
3. I have created gtk adjustment for vertical scrolling purpose
4. I have created gtk vertical scrollbar and with the adjustment
   created above.
5. I filled the treeview with some data.
6. I tried to catch the signal when the scrollbar is moved up or dowm 
   using :

`gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(vscrollbar), "value_changed",G_CALLBACK(my_function),NULL);`

My signal handler looks like below:

```
void  my_function(GtkWidget *widget)
{
printf("Hi\n");
}
```

As seen above it prints a `Hi` whenever the scrollbar is moved one step up or one step down.
But i want to print `up` when its moved up or `down` when its moved down.

```
void  my_function(GtkWidget *widget)
{
if(/*  movement is up, How to identify? */)
printf("UP\n");
if(/* movement is down, How to identify */)
printf("DOWN\n");
}
```

I am complete new person when it comes to gtk programming.
Can anybody please suggest what do i need to do for this?

Comment: btw, you have no need of creating the GtkAdjustment, nor the scrollbar.
1. Create a GtkScrolledWindow (null, null)
2. Create a GtkTreeView and add it with gtk_container_add

That will do, now, just need to hook into the signal from the adjustment created automatically by the scrolled-window.

Also, you should use *g_signal_connect* instead. Probably, you need to check newers versions of Gtk+

Answer (score 1):

First, a suggestion: check the latest API reference, even if you have to use old libraries. That will help you not write code that is already obsolete (gtk_signal_connect and GTK_OBJECT look quite ... ancient to anyone working with current GTK+). And if you can actually use current GTK+, do so.

As to your problem, you are correct that the API does not tell you the direction or magnitude  of the change. You could use a "static gdouble last_value" in your signal handler and compare that to the current value to find out the direction (and don't forget to set last_value after that :)).